# Distance Matrix results

Tags: php, json, laravel, google-maps-api-3, google-distancematrix-api

I am having difficulty putting a DistanceMatrix API result into JSON format.

This is the var_dump of the `$response` (I use Ivory\googlempas plugin in Laravel 5.1)

```
object(Ivory\GoogleMap\Services\DistanceMatrix\DistanceMatrixResponse)#694 (4) { ["status":protected]=> string(2) "OK" ["destinations":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "Milan, Italy" } ["origins":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "Rome, Italy" } ["rows":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(Ivory\GoogleMap\Services\DistanceMatrix\DistanceMatrixResponseRow)#693 (1) { ["elements":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(Ivory\GoogleMap\Services\DistanceMatrix\DistanceMatrixResponseElement)#692 (3) { ["status":protected]=> string(2) "OK" ["distance":protected]=> object(Ivory\GoogleMap\Services\Base\Distance)#690 (2) { ["text":protected]=> string(6) "572 km" ["value":protected]=> int(572343) } ["duration":protected]=> object(Ivory\GoogleMap\Services\Base\Duration)#691 (2) { ["text":protected]=> string(15) "5 hours 42 mins" ["value":protected]=> int(20517) } } } } } }
```

How i can return it in a JSON array?

Answer (score 0):

Try using type hinting:

```
$json = json_encode( (array)$response );
```

### Update:

This is bit of hacky, but will solve your issue.
Considering you have encoded your object to json in `$json` variable you can use `str_replace()` method to replace the unwanted `/u0000` i.e. null characters.

```
$json = str_replace('\\u0000', '',$json);
```

Comment: ["{\"\\u0000*\\u0000text\":\"572 km\",\"\\u0000*\\u0000value\":572343}"]

I got this response with your suggestion. Now how i can use 572343 value?

Comment: where do you want to use this json. In your front end ?

Comment: Yes i have converted it to string now and i output this: ["O:38:\"Ivory\\GoogleMap\\Services\\Base\\Distance\":2:{s:7:\"\u0000*\u0000text\";s:6:\"572 km\";s:8:\"\u0000*\u0000value\";i:572343;}"]

Now need to fetch for use in frontend 572343 value

Comment: what about the previous one

Comment: got this now: ["O:37:\"Ivory\\GoogleMap\\Service\\Base\\Distance\":2:{s:43:\"\u0000Ivory\\GoogleMap\\Service\\Base\\Distance\u0000text\";s:6:\"572 km\";s:44:\"\u0000Ivory\\GoogleMap\\Service\\Base\\Distance\u0000value\";i:572343;}"] i need to fetch only 572343

Comment: where do you get this value, in PHP or JS ? And is this the exact response ?